# Wordpress: Convert seconds to minutes and seconds

Tags: php, wordpress, time

I use a custom field called `duration` and the value is in seconds.

To insert it in post I use

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true); ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true); ?>`

My question is: How can I convert the `duration` value to minutes and seconds?

Thank you!

Comment: Use division to calculate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but it's fairly simple math.

```
$duration_in_seconds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true);
$minutes = floor($duration_in_seconds / 60);
$seconds = $duration_in_seconds - (60 * $minutes);
echo $minutes . ":" . str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: You can use a modulo to extract the seconds: `$seconds = $duration_in_seconds % 60;`

Comment: @Diamondo25 Agreed, modulo is a simpler way to get the remainder. Thanks.

Comment: There is a WordPress builtin function for that, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a nice time diff in WordPress, custom code with PHP could do the trick, but there is a better way of doing it, by using the built-in function [`human_time_diff()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/).

The advantage of using this is that it will be using the chosen date/time format from admin settings and also will be i18n compliant.

Answer (score -1):

This is not wordpress, can you please look into http://www.php.net/strtotime there you will see how to convert the times in php but first you need to declare it as variable:

so

```
<?php 
$duration = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true);

// previous to PHP 5.1.0 you would compare with -1, instead of false
if (($timestamp = strtotime($duration)) === false) {
    echo "The string ($str) is not Date";
} else {
    echo date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($duration));
}
?>
```

Check your php version to play with those, and you can check more about the date references.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp

Make sure you have the right php version as well, some minor modifications can be found in the date.

Comment: It's not because you don't know WordPress that you need to make this kind of answer. WordPress has built-in functions (that use the one of PHP of course) that are internationalization and customization compliants.
So I guess that was the question, of how to display properly in WordPress seconds into something more human reading form.